# What does "Get help from an authority figure or trusted friend" when removing a tag in Facebook do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

When clicking on "report/remove tag" what does the option "Get help from an authority figure or trusted friend" do? Does it actually contact the local police or something? Just out of curiosity...

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer, but in [this Mashable article](http://mashable.com/2011/03/10/facebook-anti-bullying/) it’s stated that

> If the user wishes to report the content to Facebook, he or she can also choose to include a trusted authority figure, such as a teacher or parent, as a contact in that incident report.

Comment: Weird, how would it know who a teacher or parent is? I guess it asks.